# Why is decltype for nlohmann json object different?

Tags: c++11, decltype, typeid, nlohmann-json

How do I extract information of underlying datatype from nlohmann object?
Since the values are stored as primitive datatypes in the json why don't it give the output like `a` and `b` below?

I see typedef as below for ordered json.

```
nlohmann::basic_json<nlohmann::ordered_map,std::vector, std::string, bool, std::int64_t, std::uint64_t, double>;
```

So it's clear the type of values it's storing(?).

```
int main()
{
  json js;
  js["key1"] = 1L;
  js["key2"]  = 0.111f;

  auto a = 1L;
  auto b = 0.111f;


  decltype(js["key1"]) x = js["key1"];
  decltype(js["key2"]) y = js["key2"];

  cout<<typeid(a).name()<<endl;
  cout<<typeid(b).name()<<endl;
  cout<<typeid(x).name()<<endl;
  cout<<typeid(y).name()<<endl;

}
```

Output:

```
l
f
N8nlohmann10basic_jsonINS_11ordered_mapESt6vectorNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEblmdSaNS_14adl_serializerES2_IhSaIhEEEE
N8nlohmann10basic_jsonINS_11ordered_mapESt6vectorNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEblmdSaNS_14adl_serializerES2_IhSaIhEEEE
```

Answer (score 0):

`operator[]` will return a`nlohmann::basic_json &` type that is used to hold the value.

The output you are seeing is the mangled specialization of the `nlohmann::basic_json` template class that has been typedef'd for ordered JSON.

That is

```cpp
nlohmann::basic_json<nlohmann::ordered_map,std::vector, std::string, bool, std::int64_t, std::uint64_t, double>;
```

corresponds to

```cpp
N8nlohmann10basic_jsonINS_11ordered_mapESt6vectorNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEblmdSaNS_14adl_serializerES2_IhSaIhEEEE
```

So what happens when you use `operator[]` e.g. `js["key1"]` is that it returns a reference to that `basic_json` type specialization as that is how the storage works internally.

However, nlohmann also provides implicit conversions for stl types and so the example below would implicitly convert the `nlohmann::basic_json` types returned by `operator[]` in to the (original) numeric types

```cpp
  auto a = 1L;
  auto b = 0.111f;

  long x = js["key1"];
  float y = js["key2"];

  cout<<typeid(a).name()<<endl;
  cout<<typeid(b).name()<<endl;
  cout<<typeid(x).name()<<endl;
  cout<<typeid(y).name()<<endl;
```

The implicit conversion is not restricted to converting it to the original type. E.g the following in which the original `long` is now converted to an `int` and the `float` to a `double` would also work

```cpp
  js["key1"] = 1L;
  js["key2"]  = 0.111f;

  int x = js["key1"];
  double y = js["key2"];
```